# Get the records which are not present in second table with join

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

I need the records where pid is NULL from the following result set:

```
pid    users_fee_schedule_students_name users_fee_schedule_students_uid

8       users                   6           MBA in IT   1   1337097600  3   6   user    250000
9       users                   6           MBA in IT   2   1337184000  3   7   user    250000
NULL    ashuser                 277         MBA in IT   1   1337097600  3   6   user    250000
NULL    ashuser                 277         MBA in IT   2   1337184000  3   7   user    250000
10      sriuser                 66          MBA in IT   1   1337097600  3   6   user    250000
NULL    sriuser                 66          MBA in IT
```

I SQL query to get the above result set is

```
SELECT FSP.pid,  users_fee_schedule_students.name AS users_fee_schedule_students_name, users_fee_schedule_students.uid AS users_fee_schedule_students_uid, fee_schedule.name AS fee_schedule_name, fee_schedule_instalments.instalment_no AS fee_schedule_instalments_instalment_no, fee_schedule_instalments.payable_by AS fee_schedule_instalments_payable_by, fee_schedule.fid AS fid, fee_schedule_instalments.iid AS fee_schedule_instalments_iid, 'user' AS field_data_field_school_course_user_entity_type, SUM(fee_schedule_instalments.amount) AS fee_schedule_instalments_amount
FROM 
ic_fee_schedule AS fee_schedule
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_students AS fee_schedule_students ON fee_schedule.fid = fee_schedule_students.fid
LEFT JOIN ic_users AS users_fee_schedule_students ON fee_schedule_students.uid = users_fee_schedule_students.uid
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_instalments AS fee_schedule_instalments ON fee_schedule.fid = fee_schedule_instalments.fid
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_payments AS FSP ON fee_schedule.fid = FSP.fid AND fee_schedule_students.uid = FSP.uid AND fee_schedule_instalments.iid = FSP.iid
WHERE (( (fee_schedule.fid = '3' ) ))
GROUP BY users_fee_schedule_students_name, users_fee_schedule_students_uid, fee_schedule_name, fee_schedule_instalments_instalment_no, fee_schedule_instalments_payable_by, fid , fee_schedule_instalments_iid
```

I think 
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_payments AS FSP need to change with some other type of join. Checking on it.....

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please use sql fiddle to put your structure and tell us clearly what you really want

Comment: Sorry not getting what is sql fiddle?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ click it and you will know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can simply add a WHERE clause "AND FSP.pid IS NULL" since you're doing a left join on FSP.

Try this:

```
SELECT FSP.pid,  users_fee_schedule_students.name AS users_fee_schedule_students_name, users_fee_schedule_students.uid AS users_fee_schedule_students_uid, fee_schedule.name AS fee_schedule_name, fee_schedule_instalments.instalment_no AS fee_schedule_instalments_instalment_no, fee_schedule_instalments.payable_by AS fee_schedule_instalments_payable_by, fee_schedule.fid AS fid, fee_schedule_instalments.iid AS fee_schedule_instalments_iid, 'user' AS field_data_field_school_course_user_entity_type, SUM(fee_schedule_instalments.amount) AS fee_schedule_instalments_amount
FROM ic_fee_schedule AS fee_schedule
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_students AS fee_schedule_students ON fee_schedule.fid = fee_schedule_students.fid
LEFT JOIN ic_users AS users_fee_schedule_students ON fee_schedule_students.uid = users_fee_schedule_students.uid
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_instalments AS fee_schedule_instalments ON fee_schedule.fid = fee_schedule_instalments.fid
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_payments AS FSP ON fee_schedule.fid = FSP.fid AND fee_schedule_students.uid = FSP.uid AND fee_schedule_instalments.iid = FSP.iid
WHERE fee_schedule.fid = '3'
AND FSP.pid IS NULL
GROUP BY users_fee_schedule_students_name, users_fee_schedule_students_uid, fee_schedule_name, fee_schedule_instalments_instalment_no, fee_schedule_instalments_payable_by, fid , fee_schedule_instalments_iid
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableB.id IS null
```

To produce the set of records only in Table A, but not in Table B, we perform the same left outer join, then exclude the records we don't want from the right side via a where clause.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html